# How to loop through an object's keys and access information from each seperately

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

Each product key is nested with more objects. I can't seem to get an idea of how to get information from each product seperately.

The code below shows what i'm trying to do. I know that it doesn't work because `.productList[i]` returns a string. I'm trying to make it so that it returns a valid object that lets me log the value of `pricePerUnit`.

```
function getProductBuyPrice(){

  const data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.hypixel.net/v2/skyblock/bazaar").getContentText());

  productList = Object.keys(data.products)

    for(let i in data.products)
    {
      console.log(data.products.productList[i].buy_summary.pricePerUnit)
    }
}

getProductBuyPrice()
```

JSON format of the data

INK_SACK:3 and CORRUPT_BAIT are just two products, theres 1000+

Comment: See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) for looping, and [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) for other aspects of accessing data.